# How to Use Session in Getherbert [Laravel]?

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, session

I use Gethebert (http://getherbert.com/) as plugin in wordpress. This one is having structure as Laravel framework.

Also it uses mostly same components as laravel used.

But my query is how to use its session.

In laravel i use,

```
Session::put('name','value');         //to Set Session Value
```

and

```
Session::get('name');                //to Get Session Value
```

But in Getherbert, I dont know the right way to use session.

Suggest me the right one....

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank to all...

Finally i got answer for using session in Getherbert[laravel],

here it is,

```
use Herbert\Framework\Session;

class Admin extends MyCore{

   function index(){
       session()->set('age',24);
       dd(session()->get('age'));
  }
}
```

OUTPUT :

```
  24
```

Comment: Great, atleast you should upvote our answer for our time :)

Answer (score 1):

You can always use standard PHP `$_SESSION`:

http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.php

For example to put:

```
$_SESSION['name'] = $value;
```

And to get:

```
$value = $_SESSION['name'];
```

Comment: Is there any other  session libraries are available ?

Answer (score 1):

Below you can find , how to use session in Laravel.

Setting a single variable in session :-

```
syntax :- Session::put('key', 'value');
example :- Session::put('email', $data['email']); //array index
           Session::put('email', $email); // a single variable
           Session::put('email', 'test@test.com'); // a string
```

Retrieving value from session :-

```
syntax :- Session::get('key');
example :- Session::get('email');
```

Checking a variable exist in session :-

```
// Checking email key exist in session.
if (Session::has('email')) {
  echo Session::get('email');
}
```

Deleting a variable from session :-

```
syntax :- Session::forget('key');
example :- Session::forget('email');
```

Removing all variables from session :-

```
Session::flush();
```

Source : http://tutsnare.com/how-to-use-session-in-laravel/

Comment: I just want to know the session handling in Getherbert not Laravel.

Comment: Getherbert is uses laravel pattern, but session handling is not same. Thats why i said..

Comment: Getherbert is uses laravel pattern, so you can handle session as Laravel do, Getherbert do not have its own session handling library, so you may use PHP session as Alexey Mezenin mentioned in below answer.

Comment: Ya you are right, but dont know how to initiate laravel session to getherbert. Because, in laravel i use "use Session" to init. But what about in getherbert ?

"use Session" is not working.

Comment: Hmm, did you try `$_SESSION['name'] = $value;` and `$value = $_SESSION['name'];`, there is nothing insecure with this.

Comment: But in case of SQL injection, this session could exposed, during that time, this sessions may handle valuable datas. So only i think about the session security. Or any other session libraries are available..?

Comment: No other libraries will do anything for security concern. To prevent sql injection, you have to take care with your queries, it has nothing to do with PHP session.